# UISegmentedControl : Private API

Tags: xcode4, uisegmentedcontrol, iphone-privateapi

I am trying to customize a UISegmentedControl with that tutorial :

http://www.framewreck.net/2010/07/custom-tintcolor-for-each-segment-of.html

Do you know if this is private api ?
I actually don't want my application to be rejected from the AppStore.

Thanks in advance,
Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is using undocumented/private APIs. I suggest finding an open source project or tutorial that fulfills your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I have to disagree to Aleksander. Looking through the code, and the comments section, this is all done using public APIs. There's no rule against poking and prodding the subviews of existing views